# Padrão de projeto ou práticas recomendadas para lidar com arquivos em disco virtual

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, design-pattern

Existe padrão ou práticas recomendadas para lidar com envio, armazenamento, publicação de arquivos e controle de acesso?

Exemplo de ambiente:

Tenho um sistema que precisará que possui cadastro de Atendimentos e Notícias e em ambos preciso permitir inserção de anexos e depois liberá-los para download ou visualização no browser conforme possível (pdf, txt, em alguns casos arquivos do office).

Também terei uma área para publicação direta, onde os arquivos serão submetidos para um diretório "virtual" selecionado pelo usuário, determinados grupos de usuários terão acesso à esses diretórios e arquivos, outros não.

Também serão disponibilizados para download e/ou visualização em browser quando possível.

Existem padrões ou práticas recomendadas para lidar com esse tipo de necessidade? 
Um detalhe importante é que não será feito o controle de acesso por usuário de um domínio. Serão usuários do sistema somente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Algumas das práticas citadas abaixo são de outras perguntas do Stack Overflow, e algumas são minhas, por empirismo. Não há um guia de boas práticas da Microsoft. Essa resposta deve servir como um bom guia de boas práticas, o qual pretendo ir atualizando conforme novas questões devam ir aparecendo.

## Existe padrão ou práticas recomendadas para lidar com envio, armazenamento, publicação de arquivos e controle de acesso?

### Envio

- Faça seus *Controllers* manipularem todo e qualquer arquivo recebido;
- Procure usar sempre formulários e a decoração `[HttpPost]` nas `Actions` do seu *Controller*;
- Procure limitar tamanhos e tempos de envio;

### Armazenamento

- Para envios de arquivos pelos usuários, evite diretórios em que possa ser feito o acesso direto por link, como o diretório `Content`, por exemplo. Use um diretório inacessível externamente;
- Se for separar por usuário, evite usar o nome do usuário para a nomenclatura dos diretórios;
- Ao receber um arquivo, mude seu nome antes de salvá-lo. Isso garante alguma segurança se alguém tentar explorar os problemas de segurança de sua aplicação usando o nome original do arquivo;
- Antes de salvar, se for um arquivo de imagem, procure redimensionar o arquivo. Se alguma coisa falhar neste redimensionamento, pode não ser **exatamente** uma imagem que o usuário enviou;
- Antes de salvar, verifique se o MIME Type do arquivo é de fato correspondente ao conteúdo dele;

### Publicação

- **Jamais** deixe seus usuários acessarem diretamente seus arquivos no caso de um Download. Forneça ao usuário um link para uma `Action` que devolva um `FileResult`;
- Ainda sobre os links, não forneça um arquivo com um link facilmente dedutível, como por exemplo uma ID inteira (`http://meusitemaroto/Arquivos/1`) ou então o nome do arquivo (`http://meusitemaroto/Arquivos/MinhaImagem1`, `http://meusitemaroto/Arquivos/MinhaImagem2`). Gere uma `string` aleatória que funcione como token ou use `Guids`;

### Controle de Acesso

- Seguindo a linha anterior, faça sua `Action` verificar o acesso através de `Attributes`. Pode ser o bom e velho `[Authorize]` ou um atributo de autorização implementado por você. Há diversas questões aqui no SOpt em que ensino a fazer isso;
- Evite permitir downloads se o usuário não estiver autenticado. Se isso não for possível, valide cada download usando tokens de autorização e contadores de download, ou até mesmo expirando o arquivo depois de um tempo.