# Recuperar imagem através do path e exibir

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5

Criei o seguinte método para salvar uma imagem no banco de dados

```
public ActionResult enviaArquivo(UsurioViewModel arq)      
 {

    try {
            string nomeArquivo ="";

            if (arq.Arquivo != null && arq.Arquivo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                nomeArquivo= Path.GetFileName(arq.Arquivo.FileName);
                var caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), nomeArquivo);
                arq.File.SaveAs(caminho);
                arq.CaminhoArquivo = caminho;
            }
            ViewBag.Mensagem = "Arquivo: " + nomeArquivo+ ", enviado com sucesso.";
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Mensagem("Erro:" + ex);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Agora preciso criar um método para recuperar a imagem do servidor e exibi-la no html, li alguns tutoriais e assisti alguns videos, mas ainda não está claro para mim como fazer. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grata!!! :)

Comment: Olá Ana, o que exatamente não está claro? Como você disse que quer a imagem no html, bastaria incluir seu caminho em uma tag `img`, uma vez que você tem o caminho e nome da imagem quando fez o upload: `<img src='/imagens/nomearquivo'/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre este código, fiz algumas modificações para poder embasar minha resposta:

```
public ActionResult enviaArquivo(UsuarioViewModel arq)      
 {
    // Não use try ... catch em Actions. 
    // O evento correto para interceptar exceções é o OnException de Controller.
    // try {
        string nomeArquivo ="";

        if (arq.Arquivo != null && arq.Arquivo.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            nomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(arq.Arquivo.FileName);
            var caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), nomeArquivo);
            arq.File.SaveAs(caminho);
            arq.CaminhoArquivo = caminho;

            // Depois de gravar o arquivo, o ideal é que você guarde
            // o nome do arquivo associado a alguma coisa. 
            // Não é uma boa ideia usar o nome do arquivo para recuperá-lo.
            // Minha sugestão é:

            var imagem = new Imagem 
            {
                CaminhoArquivo = arq.CaminhoArquivo
            };

            contexto.Imagens.Add(imagem);
            contexto.SaveChanges();

            ViewBag.Mensagem = "Arquivo: " + nomeArquivo + ", enviado com sucesso.";
            // Se o upload do arquivo ocorreu com sucesso, redirecione
            // o usuário para algum lugar.
            return RedirectToAction("Sucesso", imagem);
        }


    // }
    // catch (Exception ex)
    // {
    //    ViewBag.Mensagem("Erro:" + ex);
    // }

    // Este ponto deve ser executado apenas se o Upload falhou.
    return View();
}
```

Ou seja, a imagem é recuperada através do banco de dados. Não precisa ser assim. O importante é não expôr o nome porque isso pode ser um problema de segurança. [Explico tudo isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41883/padr%C3%A3o-de-projeto-ou-pr%C3%A1ticas-recomendadas-para-lidar-com-arquivos-em-disco-virt/41888#41888).

[O download já expliquei aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200777/disponibilizar-download-de-arquivo-do-servidor/200798#200798):

```
public FileResult Download(int id)
{
    var caminhoDaImagem = /* Aqui você usa id que vem por parâmetro pra fazer alguma operação que seleciona o caminho da imagem de algum lugar */
    byte[] dadosArquivo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoDaImagem);
    return File(dadosArquivo, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg, "nomedoarquivo.jpg");
}
```